# Phoenix seems to be preventing image caching for <img> tags dynamically added to the DOM

Tags: phoenix-framework

Each time the Add button is pressed in this example, a request goes to the server even though the cache-control header is set to prevent that.

cachetest.html.eex:

```html
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<div id="avatars"></div>

<script>
function add() {
    let i = document.createElement('img');
    i.src = 'http://localhost:4000/avatars/64e91e0a-5015-4ef6-bd0d-915a84f9f7bc/image.jpg';
    let d = document.getElementById('avatars');
    d.appendChild(i);
}
</script>
```

avatar_controller.ex

```
...
  def image(conn, %{"avatar_id" => id}) do
    a = Avatars.get_avatar(id)
    img = a.image_jpg
    conn
    |> Conn.put_resp_content_type("image/jpeg")
    |> Conn.put_resp_header("cache-control", "max-age=3600, public")
    |> Conn.send_resp(200, img)
  end
...
```

When I copy cachetest.html.eex to index.html and open it directly in a browser, the caching works fine and no additional requests are made to the server.

How can I get the caching to work within Phoenix?

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, caching was disabled in the browser dev tools. Turning it back on fixed the problem.

[image: Location of the Disable cache toggle]